# How to remove Ubuntu 11.10 after it is installed alongside Windows

Tags: 11.10, windows-7, uninstall

I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 alongside Windows 7. Now I want to uninstall Ubuntu, but I want my Windows 7 to be safe, i.e. intact with applications and documents in Windows.

I have not used Wubi, just installed alongside Windows. I am a new user. 
Please help me and tell me how to uninstall Ubuntu 11.10 while preserving my Windows installation.

Answer (score 1):

1. Start the [OS-Uninstaller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller) utility from a live disk
2. Select what operating system you want to uninstall.

[image: os-uninstaller-fr]

3. Apply
4. Reboot your computer, and voila, only Windows is on your computer!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to boot your system with Win7 then Right Click on **Computer** from start menu and select **Manage**. In the Management Console, select **Disk Management** from side bar and delete all Linux partitions from volume List.

After deleting Linux partitions, insert your Win7 DVD into the DVD Drive and restart your computer. Note that to start the computer from DVD, the computer must be configured to start from the DVD drive.

Finally, follow [these instructions on Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392).

Comment: Thank you. If I restart with my Windows recovery cd, will my apllications and documents of windows 7 remain safe as earlier?

Comment: Yes. They remain safe. I tried that and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Boot your computer with win7, right click on the **My Computer** icon, click on **Manage** than open **disk management** and remove all Linux drives. Now below you see blocks of all windows partitions. Right click on C: partition and click on extend drive and add your free space in this drive.

You can also make a new drive using this free space: right click on the free space block and click on **New Simple Volume**.

For More Infomation [see this article on How To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/101862/how-to-manage-partitions-on-windows-without-downloading-any-other-software/)